# count more time for one day in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I want to Collect the time recorded during check-in and check out from the employees to one day

```
select ahmad.authors.auther_id
      , concat( ahmad.authors.firstName
                ," " 
                , ahmad.authors.lastName
      ) as FullName
      , count(Date(ahmad.authors.date_y)) as CheckIn 
from ahmad.authors 
group by FullName
```

[image]
Every employee has a card. He enters the company every day once or more than once and also leaves once or more than once, but I am required to calculate the number of days he came to the job in a week,[image: In the picture, it shows I should get one number for Ahmad and not two even though the number of visits was two on the same day]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and repace the images

Comment: Just use COUNT(DISTINCT ...)

Comment: Thank you so much,  it is work with DISINCT